# boolean method trouble

Tags: java

Im trying to implement a method to return the boolean true or false. The method initializes the boolean isMatch to true or false based on the if and else statement.

```
public class BooleanTest {
   int num;
   boolean isMatch;

   public BooleanTest() {
     num = 10;
   }

   public boolean isMatch() { //variable is already initialize to 10 from constructor
     if (num == 10)
       isMatch = true;
     else
       isMatch = false;
     return isMatch;
   }

   public static void main(String[] arg) {
     BooleanTest s = new BooleanTest();

     System.out.println(s.isMatch);
   }
}
```

The outprint of isMatch should be true, but i get the output isMatch is false. Is my boolean method wrong and how can i fix it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you post how you call this method in your code?

Comment: Show your `main()` method.

Comment: Your code is fine , the problem is elsewhere . Can you post your calling class and full code of BooleanTest ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to rename function to different name.

Comment: i have edit the program. plz take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, your entire `isMatch` method would be better collapsed to:

```
public boolean isMatch() {
    return num == 10;
}
```

Secondly, your existing code really *will* work, unless you're changing the value of `num`. You should look at whatever diagnostics you're using to show the output as `false`... I suspect they're misleading you. Is it possible that you're printing out the value of the *field* called `isMatch` rather than calling the method? That would explain it. This is one reason why it's a bad idea to have a method with the same name as a field. Additionally, I'd recommend making your fields private.

Short but complete example showing both the working method call and the "failed" field access (working fine, but not doing what you want):

```
public class BooleanTest {
    private int num;
    private boolean isMatch;

    public BooleanTest() {
        num = 10;
    }

    public boolean isMatch() {
        return num == 10;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BooleanTest test = new BooleanTest();
        System.out.println(test.isMatch()); // true
        System.out.println(test.isMatch); // false
    }
}
```

It's not clear why you've got the field at all, to be honest - I'd remove it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to call it like

```
b.isMatch()
```

not like

```
b.isMatch
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you Done something like this ?:

```
public class BooleanTest {
   int num;
   boolean isMatch;

   public BooleanTest() {
     num = 10;
   }

   public boolean isMatch() { //variable is already initialize to 10 from constructor
     if (num == 10)
       isMatch = true;
     else
       isMatch = false;
     return isMatch;
   }
   public static void main(String st[])//test your code in main..
    {
      BooleanTest bt = new BooleanTest();//constructor of BooleanTest is called 
      System.out.println(bt.isMatch());//Check the value returned by isMatch()
    }
}
```

**EDIT**  
 Your edited post is showing that in `main` you are printing `isMatch` instead of `isMatch()` which is `false`  by default. .. You should use `isMatch()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you when executing you are calling the method `isMatch()` with braces else you will be refering to the field `isMatch`. Should be as follows :

```
BooleanTest bt = new BooleanTest();
bt.isMatch(); // include () and not bt.isMatch
```

Change

```
System.out.println(s.isMatch);
```

to

```
System.out.println(s.isMatch());
```